# Email validation (RFC 5322) for Postgresql

Tags: regex, postgresql, validation, plpgsql

Please, I would like to have a function that checks the email (I copied the regex from [this website](https://emailregex.com/), I just scaped the ' signs and didn't change anything else) in the most robust way. It's not only a constraint, I need to check the parameter for search functions too.

The idea is that this function should return TRUE if the email provided is valid (RFC 5322) and FALSE if not.

```
CREATE FUNCTION _is_email_valid(p_email TEXT)
RETURNS BOOLEAN AS $$
BEGIN 
    RETURN REGEXP_MATCHES(p_email, '^(?:[a-z0-9!#$%&''*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&''*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*|"(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])*")@(?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\[(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21-\x5a\x53-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])+)\])^','g');
END
$$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What doesn't work?

Comment: I'd have no trust in a regular expression that ends with `^`. Why don't you ask the author of that beauty?